# Build ASP.NET Core from Source, restore.cmd/sh fails, dotnet-install cannot download "servicing" versions

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to build ASP.NET Core from Source. I checked out the [release/6.0 branch](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/release/6.0). According to their [official guide](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/docs/BuildFromSource.md) I need to run `.\restore.cmd`.

Unfortunately it fails with dotnet-install cannot downloading "servicing" versions:

[image: restore.cmd fails with dotnet-install cannot downloading "servicing" versions]

```
Attempting to install dotnet from public location.
dotnet-install: Downloading link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x64.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x64.zip
dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x64.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x64.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
Failed to install dotnet from public location.
Attempting to install dotnet from public location.
dotnet-install: Downloading link: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x64.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x64.zip
dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x64.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x64.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
Failed to install dotnet from public location.
Failed to install dotnet from any of the specified locations.
C:\Users\manuel.naujoks\.nuget\packages\microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk\6.0.0-beta.22314.7\tools\InstallDotNetCore.targets(15,5): error : dotnet-install failed [C:\Users\manuel.naujoks\.nuget\packages\microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk\6.0.0-beta.22314.7\tools\Tools.proj]
Attempting to install dotnet from public location.
dotnet-install: Downloading link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x86.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x86.zip
dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x86.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x86.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
Failed to install dotnet from public location.
Attempting to install dotnet from public location.
dotnet-install: Downloading link: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x86.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x86.zip
dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x86.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetbuilds.azureedge.net/public/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-win-x86.6.0.7-servicing.22322.2.zip
Failed to install dotnet from public location.
Failed to install dotnet from any of the specified locations.
C:\Users\manuel.naujoks\.nuget\packages\microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk\6.0.0-beta.22314.7\tools\InstallDotNetCore.targets(15,5): error : dotnet-install failed [C:\Users\manuel.naujoks\.nuget\packages\microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk\6.0.0-beta.22314.7\tools\Tools.proj]
```

I found this somehow related [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41656), which claims `eng\Versions.props` should not be manipulated but also indicated that not all versions are publicly available.

What am I missing? Is the release/6.0 branch not supposed to be built? Why can the versions specified in the `Versions.props` not be downloaded?

Try it yourself, the link is dead: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/6.0.7-servicing.22322.2/dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-servicing.22322.2-win-x64.zip

Or is it only supposed to be built by Microsoft employees?

Comment: I filed an issue on github as well: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43133

Comment: I also encountered this problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't believe it works for non-microsoft employees.

Comment: The problem was solved after I deleted the entire .dotnet folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be an older version of dotnet-install, as discovered in this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43133).

The problem disappeared when the `.dotnet` and `.tools` folders were deleted. It recommends that in the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/docs/BuildErrors.md#errors-when-restoring-older-clones), I just didnt think it would apply to my scenario.